# Tamil keyboard 99

Tags: javascript

trying to add tamil virtual keyboard99 to a webpage..i have some gif image used as a keys in the keyboard..the problem is ,here the keyboard is fixed. how to open the keyboard only that keyboard.png is clicked.

```js
   
var mouseOverStyleVal = "2px inset #ccc";  
var mouseOutStyleVal = "2px outset #E9E9E9";  
var keyPressStyleVal = "1px inset #ccc";   
var textControlIdValue = "editor"; 
  
var keyCode;    
var key;      
var keyCheck;    
var prevChar;    
var newKey;    
var toggleEngTam = -1;   
var capsLockOn = 1;   
var shiftOn = 1;   

   
var consecutiveCons = 0;
var consecutiveConsVal = "";
var disableJoin=0;
var caretOn = 0;
var consecutiveCaretOn = 0;
   
function addCharKeyPress(textControl, evt, keyChecker){
 hideStatusBarBottom();
 listenCurrentEvent(evt);
 toggleShift(keyCode,16,16);
 toggleCapsLock(keyCode,20)
 if(capsLockOn==1|| shiftOn==1){
  keyCode = String.fromCharCode(keyCode).toUpperCase().charCodeAt();
  if (keyCode) key = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
 }
 if(toggleEngTam == -1 )
 {
   keyCheck = keyChecker(keyCode, key);
   return transKey(textControl, evt, keyChecker);
 }
}

function listenCurrentEvent(evt){
 if(typeof evt.which != 'undefined') keyCode = evt.which;
 else if(typeof evt.keyCode != 'undefined') keyCode = evt.keyCode;
 else if(typeof evt.charCode != 'undefined') keyCode = evt.charCode;
 else keyCode = 0;
   if (keyCode) key = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
 
}
function toggleShift(title,val1,val2){
 if(title == val1 ||title==val2) shiftOn = 1; //Shift key is in On mode
 else shiftOn = 0; //Shift key is in off mode
}
function toggleCapsLock(title,val){
 if(title == val) capsLockOn = -(capsLockOn);
}
function hideStatusBarBottom(){
 document.getElementById('shiftcaps_status').innerHTML = "";
}
var enterKeyCount=0;
 
function engToTam (keyCode, key) {
 if( keyCode!= 13) 
 cha = langMapping[String.fromCharCode(keyCode)][0];
 else
  cha = ""; //To fix the "langMapping[..][0] is null or not an object" error when press Enter 
 if (cha) {
     return {  replaceKey: true,
               newKeyCode: cha.charCodeAt(),  
               newKey: cha      
    };
   }
   else {
     return { cancelKey: false };
   }
}
function transKey (textControl, evt, keyChecker) {
   if (keyCode && window.event && !window.opera) { 
     if (keyCheck.cancelKey) {
        return false;
     }
     else if (keyCheck.replaceKey) {
   if (window.event.preventDefault) {
          window.event.preventDefault();
        }
   setNewKey(textControl,keyCheck.newKey,engTamExp[key]);
   return false;
     }
     else {
        return true;
     }
   }
   else if (typeof textControl.setSelectionRange != 'null') { 
     if (keyCheck.cancelKey) {
        if (evt.preventDefault) {
          evt.preventDefault();
        }
        return false;
     }
     else if (keyCheck.replaceKey) {
   if (evt.preventDefault) {
    evt.preventDefault();
   }
   setNewKey(textControl,keyCheck.newKey,engTamExp[key]);
        return false;
     }
     else {
        return true;
     } 
   }
   else if (keyCheck.cancelKey) {
     if (evt.preventDefault) {
        evt.preventDefault();
     }
     return false;
   }
   else {
     return true;
   }
}
function setNewKey(textControl,newKeyVal,vowGlyph){
 var pos = getCursorPosition(textControl);
 prevChar = getPrevChar(textControl.value,pos); 
 newKey = newKeyVal;

 
  
 analyzedNewKey(vowGlyph);
 textControl.value = textControl.value.substring(0, pos) + newKey + textControl.value.substring(pos);
 textControl.focus();
 inc = pos+newKey.length;
 setCursorPosition(textControl,inc,inc,oldpos=pos);
}
function getCursorPosition(textControl){
 if(document.selection)
  return getCursorPositionIE(textControl);
 else if(typeof textControl.setSelectionRange != 'undefined')
  return getCursorPositionFF(textControl);
 else 
  return textControl.length;
}
function getCursorPositionIE(textControl){
 var len = textControl.value.length;
 var pos = -1;
 if(document.selection)
 {
  sel = document.selection.createRange();
  obj = textControl.createTextRange();
  obj.moveToBookmark(sel.getBookmark());
  obj.moveEnd('character',textControl.value.length);
  pos = len - obj.text.length; 
 }
  
  
 return pos;
}
function getCursorPositionFF(textControl){
 var currentSelectionStart=-1,currentSelectionEnd=-1;
 if(typeof textControl.setSelectionRange != 'undefined'){
  currentSelectionStart = textControl.selectionStart;
  currentSelectionEnd = textControl.selectionEnd;
  }
 return currentSelectionStart;
}
function getPrevChar(txt,currentPosition){
 return txt.substring(currentPosition-1,currentPosition);
}
function analyzedNewKey(vowGlyph){

 newKeyPerm = newKey;//To keep the original value of newKey
 
 if(prevChar){  
   
  
  if(prevChar==newKey && tamCon.toString().indexOf(prevChar)!=-1 && disableJoin!=1)
   consecutiveCons++;
  else consecutiveCons = 0;

  if(newKey==prevChar && newKey!=consecutiveConsVal && consecutiveConsVal!="")
   consecutiveCons=1;
  
  
  if(newKey==prevChar && tamCon.toString().indexOf(prevChar)!=-1 && consecutiveCons%2 && consecutiveCons!=0 && disableJoin!=1)
  {
   newKey = "்"+newKey;
   consecutiveConsVal = prevChar;
   disableJoin = 0;
  }

 
  if( ((prevChar=="ங" && newKey=="க") || (prevChar=="ஞ" && newKey=="ச")|| (prevChar=="ந" && newKey=="த")|| (prevChar=="ண" && newKey=="ட")|| (prevChar=="ம" && newKey=="ப")|| (prevChar=="ன" && newKey=="ற"))  && disableJoin!=1)
  {
   newKey = "்"+newKey;
   consecutiveCons++;
   
  }
  
  
  if(tamCon.toString().indexOf(prevChar)!=-1 && tamVow.toString().indexOf(newKey)!=-1 && vowGlyph && disableJoin!=1)
   newKey = vowGlyph;

  
  if(newKeyPerm=="அ" && tamCon.toString().indexOf(prevChar)!=-1 )
  {
   newKey = "";
   disableJoin=1;
  }else disableJoin = 0;


 
  if(newKey==tamPul && tamCon.toString().indexOf(prevChar)==-1 )
   newKey = "ஃ";
  
 }else{
  //to remove 1st character pulli
  if(newKey==tamPul)
   newKey = "";
 }
 

 if(caretOn && newKeyPerm==".") {newKey = "•";caretOn = 0;}
 if(caretOn && newKeyPerm=="௵") {newKey = "©";caretOn = 0;}//v1.2.1


 if(caretOn && newKeyPerm=="7") {newKey = "‘";caretOn = 0;}
 if(caretOn && newKeyPerm=="8") {newKey = "’";caretOn = 0;}
 if(caretOn && newKeyPerm=="9") {newKey = "“";caretOn = 0;}
 if(caretOn && newKeyPerm=="0") {newKey = "”";caretOn = 0;}
 if(caretOn && newKeyPerm=="s") {newKey = " ";caretOn = 0;}
 
 
 if((caretOn && newKeyPerm=="ஆ") || (caretOn && newKeyPerm=="இ")|| (caretOn && newKeyPerm=="ஈ")|| (caretOn && newKeyPerm=="உ")|| (caretOn && newKeyPerm=="ஊ")|| (caretOn && newKeyPerm=="எ")|| (caretOn && newKeyPerm=="ஏ")|| (caretOn && newKeyPerm=="ஐ")|| (caretOn && newKeyPerm=="ஒ")|| (caretOn && newKeyPerm=="ஓ")|| (caretOn && newKeyPerm=="ஔ") ) {newKey = uirVis[newKeyPerm];caretOn = 0;}//v1.2.1
 if(caretOn && newKeyPerm =="^"){newKey = "^";caretOn = 0;consecutiveCaretOn=1}
 
 if(caretOn && newKey=="ஃ") {newKey = "்";caretOn = 0;}
 

 if(consecutiveCaretOn!=1 && newKeyPerm == "^"){ 
  newKey = ""; 
  caretOn = 1
 }
 consecutiveCaretOn = 0; //Tamil99 Rule = 10
 
}
function setCursorPosition(textControl,oStart,oEnd,oldpos) {
 if( textControl.setSelectionRange ) {
  textControl.setSelectionRange(oStart,oEnd);
 } 
 else if( textControl.createTextRange ) {
  var obj = textControl.createTextRange();
  obj.collapse(true);
  obj.moveEnd('character',oEnd);
  obj.moveStart('character',oStart);
  obj.select();
 }
}

 
function addW3Tamil (character) {
 var title = parseInt(character.id);
 var textControl = document.getElementById(textControlIdValue);
 textControl.focus();
 character.style.border = keyPressStyleVal;
 toggleCapsLock(title,29);
 if(!(title==29 || title==42 || title==53)){
  if(shiftOn || capsLockOn==1) title = title+500;
  newKey = "";
  if(clickMapping[title])
  if(toggleEngTam == -1){
   if(langMapping[clickMapping[title]][0])
    newKey = langMapping[clickMapping[title]][0]; 
  }else{
   if(clickMapping[title])
    newKey = clickMapping[title]; 
  }
  setNewKey(textControl,newKey,uirVis[newKey]);
 }
 toggleShift(title,42,53);
 displayStatusBar(); 
 displayStatusBarBottom();

}
function displayStatusBar(){
 
 document.getElementById('lang_status').innerHTML = "<b>Language Mode</b> = <a href='#' title='Indicates the Input Language mode; Click here to change the language mode' onclick='toggleEngTam=-toggleEngTam;displayStatusBar();'>"+((toggleEngTam==-1)?"  Tamil":"English")+"</a><i>(To change, click on the link OR press</i> <font color='brown'>F12</font><i> key)</i><br />";    
 document.getElementById('keyboard_status').style.width = "90%";
 document.getElementById('keyboard_status').style.padding = "3px";
 document.getElementById('keyboard_status').style.border = "1px solid #fff";
}
function displayStatusBarBottom(){
 document.getElementById('shiftcaps_status').innerHTML = "<b>SHIFT</b> = "+((shiftOn==1)?" On":"Off")+"; <b>CAPSLOCK</b> = "+((capsLockOn==1)?" On":"Off");    
}

   
function toggleLangMode(evt)
{
 listenCurrentEvent(evt);
 if(keyCode == 123) toggleEngTam = -(toggleEngTam); //F12 key's keyCode = 123
 toggleShift(keyCode,16,16); //shift key's keyCode = 16
 toggleCapsLock(keyCode,20) //capslock key's keyCode = 20
 displayStatusBar();
}
function resetIt()
{

document.getElementById('searchResult_searchword').value='';
document.getElementById('editor').value='';

}
function keyDownBorder(obj){
 if(keyIdCode[keyCode])
  document.getElementById(keyIdCode[keyCode]).style.border = mouseOverStyleVal;
}
function keyUpBorder(kid){
 for(i=1;i<=60;i++)
  document.getElementById(i).style.border = mouseOutStyleVal;
}
function overW3Tamil(obj){
 obj.style.border = mouseOverStyleVal;
}
function Clear()
   {  
   document.getElementById('editor').value = "";
      }
   function fncEnter()
     {
        document.getElementById('editor').click();
     }
 function back() {
  var input, num;
  input = document.getElementById('editor');
  num = input.value;
  input.value = num.slice(0,num.length-1);
  return false;
}
function outW3Tamil(obj){
 obj.style.border = mouseOutStyleVal;
}
function copyit() {
 var textControl= document.getElementById(textControlIdValue);
 var alertMsg1 = "You've selected";
 var alertMsg2="";
 textControl.focus();
 textControl.select();
 if(typeof textControl.createTextRange!= 'undefined'){
  therange=textControl.createTextRange();
  therange.execCommand("Copy");
  alertMsg2=" and copied into the clipboard successfully.";
 }else alertMsg2=" successfully.\n To copy use one of the following:\n* EDIT->COPY \nor\n* RIGHT MOUSE CLICK->COPY";
 alert(alertMsg1+alertMsg2);
}



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>w3Tamil Web Keyboard (Beta v1.2.1) - Tamil99 Keyboard Layout</title>
  
<!-- w3TamilWK - Section 1 - START --> 
<script language="JavaScript1.2" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/js/w3tamil_wk_library.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="JavaScript1.2" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/js/w3tamil_wk_mappings.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="w3tamil_wk_includes/css/w3tamil_wk_style.css" />
<!-- w3TamilWK - Section 1 - END -->  

</head>
<body>

<div id="keyboard_container">
<div id="keyboard" align="center">
 <div id="keyboard_editor">
 <form name="editorForm"> 
 <!--<input type="text" name="editor" class="keyboardInput"onkeypress="return addCharKeyPress(this, event,engToTam);" onkeyDown="toggleLangMode(event);keyDownBorder(this);" onkeyup="keyUpBorder(this)"/> -->
 

  <input type="text"name="editor"  id="editor" onkeypress="return addCharKeyPress(this, event,engToTam);" onkeyDown="toggleLangMode(event);keyDownBorder(this);" onkeyup="keyUpBorder(this)"/>
  <img src="keyboard.png"alt="keyboard">
  <br />
  
 </form>
 </div>
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <div id="row_1">
  <span id="key_1_1"><img id="1" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/approx.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_1_2"><img id="2" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/1.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_1_3_"><img id="3" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/2.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_1_4"><img id="4" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/3.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_1_5"><img id="5" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/4.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_1_6"><img id="6" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/5.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_1_7"><img id="7" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/6.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_1_8"><img id="8" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/7.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_1_9"><img id="9" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/8.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_1_10"><img id="10" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/9.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_1_11"><img id="11" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/0.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_1_12"><img id="12" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/minus.gif" width="39" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_1_13"><img id="13" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/plus.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_1_14"><img id="14" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/backspace.gif" onclick="back()"width="38" height="38" alt="" style="cursor:default" /></span>
 </div>
 <div id="row_2">
  
  <span id="key_2_2"><img id="16" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/Q.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_2_3"><img id="17" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/W.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_2_4"><img id="18" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/E.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_2_5"><img id="19" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/R.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_2_6"><img id="20" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/T.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_2_7"><img id="21" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/Y.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_2_8"><img id="22" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/U.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_2_9"><img id="23" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/I.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_2_10"><img id="24" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/O.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_2_11"><img id="25" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/P.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_2_12"><img id="26" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/BRACKET_START.gif" width="39" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_2_13"><img id="27" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/BRACKET_END.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_2_14"><img id="28" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/PIPE.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_2_1"><img id="15" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/CLEAR.gif" onclick="Clear()"width="38" height="38" alt="" style="cursor:default" /></span>
 </div>
 <div id="row_3">
  <span id="key_3_1"><img id="29" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/CAPSLOCK.gif" width="59" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_3_2"><img id="30" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/A.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_3_3"><img id="31" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/S.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_3_4"><img id="32" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/D.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_3_5"><img id="33" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/F.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_3_6"><img id="34" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/G.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_3_7"><img id="35" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/H.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_3_8"><img id="36" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/J.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_3_9"><img id="37" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/K.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_3_10"><img id="38" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/L.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_3_11"><img id="39" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/SEMICOLON.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_3_12"><img id="40" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/QUOTE.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_3_13"><img id="41" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/ENTER.gif" onclick="outW3Tamil(this)"width="56" height="38" alt="" style="cursor:default" /></span>
 </div>
 <div id="row_4">
  <span id="key_4_1"><img id="42" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/SHIFT.gif" width="76" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_4_2"><img id="43" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/Z.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_4_3"><img id="44" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/X.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_4_4"><img id="45" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/C.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_4_5"><img id="46" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/V.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_4_6"><img id="47" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/B.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_4_7"><img id="48" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/N.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_4_8"><img id="49" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/M.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_4_9"><img id="50" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/COMMA.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_4_10"><img id="51" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/STOP.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_4_11"><img id="52" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/SLASH.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_4_12"><img id="53" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/SHIFT2.gif" width="77" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
 
 </div>
 
 
</div>
</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you reduce your code to the most important parts only?

Comment: it works good...no problem is there...only thing is that i want to show keyboard only wen keyboard.png image is pressed..any idea?

Comment: k then let me post only the js file..

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i edit the code

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

**In JS:**

```
function callKeyboard(){
var keyb=document.getElementById("keyboard_appear");
if(keyb.style.display=="none")
    keyb.style.display="block";
else
    keyb.style.display="none";
}
```

**In HTML:**

- create a new div around the 4 rows of the divs and give it an id and style as shown below,

  `<div id="keyboard_appear" style="display:none">`
- Call the function defined in the js which will make the keyboard appear onclick of the image and disappear if clicked again.

  `<img src="keyboard.png"alt="keyboard" onclick="callKeyboard()">`

This the working code snippet as shown below,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Tring Reset</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="w3tamil_wk_includes/css/w3tamil_wk_style.css" />
</head>
<body> 
<div id="keyboard_container">
<div id="keyboard" align="center">
 <div id="keyboard_editor">
 <form name="editorForm"> 
 <!--<input type="text" name="editor" class="keyboardInput"onkeypress="return addCharKeyPress(this, event,engToTam);" onkeyDown="toggleLangMode(event);keyDownBorder(this);" onkeyup="keyUpBorder(this)"/> -->
 

  <input type="text"name="editor"  id="editor" onkeypress="return addCharKeyPress(this, event,engToTam);" onkeyDown="toggleLangMode(event);keyDownBorder(this);" onkeyup="keyUpBorder(this)"/>
  <img src="keyboard.png"alt="keyboard" onclick="callKeyboard(this)">
  <br />
  
 </form>
 </div>
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <div id="keyboard_appear" style="display:none">
 <div id="row_1">
  <span id="key_1_1"><img id="1" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/approx.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_1_2"><img id="2" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/1.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_1_3_"><img id="3" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/2.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_1_4"><img id="4" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/3.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_1_5"><img id="5" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/4.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_1_6"><img id="6" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/5.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_1_7"><img id="7" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/6.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_1_8"><img id="8" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/7.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_1_9"><img id="9" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/8.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_1_10"><img id="10" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/9.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_1_11"><img id="11" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/0.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_1_12"><img id="12" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/minus.gif" width="39" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_1_13"><img id="13" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/plus.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_1_14"><img id="14" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/backspace.gif" onclick="back()"width="38" height="38" alt="" style="cursor:default" /></span>
 </div>
 <div id="row_2">
  
  <span id="key_2_2"><img id="16" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/Q.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_2_3"><img id="17" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/W.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_2_4"><img id="18" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/E.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_2_5"><img id="19" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/R.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_2_6"><img id="20" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/T.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_2_7"><img id="21" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/Y.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_2_8"><img id="22" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/U.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_2_9"><img id="23" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/I.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_2_10"><img id="24" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/O.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_2_11"><img id="25" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/P.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_2_12"><img id="26" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/BRACKET_START.gif" width="39" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_2_13"><img id="27" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/BRACKET_END.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_2_14"><img id="28" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/PIPE.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_2_1"><img id="15" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/CLEAR.gif" onclick="Clear()"width="38" height="38" alt="" style="cursor:default" /></span>
 </div>
 <div id="row_3">
  <span id="key_3_1"><img id="29" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/CAPSLOCK.gif" width="59" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_3_2"><img id="30" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/A.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_3_3"><img id="31" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/S.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_3_4"><img id="32" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/D.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_3_5"><img id="33" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/F.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_3_6"><img id="34" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/G.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_3_7"><img id="35" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/H.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_3_8"><img id="36" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/J.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_3_9"><img id="37" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/K.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_3_10"><img id="38" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/L.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_3_11"><img id="39" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/SEMICOLON.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_3_12"><img id="40" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/QUOTE.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_3_13"><img id="41" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/ENTER.gif" onclick="outW3Tamil(this)"width="56" height="38" alt="" style="cursor:default" /></span>
 </div>
 <div id="row_4">
  <span id="key_4_1"><img id="42" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/SHIFT.gif" width="76" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_4_2"><img id="43" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/Z.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_4_3"><img id="44" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/X.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_4_4"><img id="45" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/C.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_4_5"><img id="46" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/V.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_4_6"><img id="47" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/B.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_4_7"><img id="48" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/N.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_4_8"><img id="49" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/M.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_4_9"><img id="50" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/COMMA.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_4_10"><img id="51" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/STOP.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_4_11"><img id="52" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/SLASH.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
  <span id="key_4_12"><img id="53" src="w3tamil_wk_includes/images99/SHIFT2.gif" width="77" height="38" alt="" onmouseover="overW3Tamil(this)" onmouseout="outW3Tamil(this)" onclick="addW3Tamil(this)" /></span>
 
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- w3TamilWK - Section 2 - END --> 
<script>
function callKeyboard(){
 var keyb=document.getElementById("keyboard_appear");
 if(keyb.style.display=="none")
  keyb.style.display="block";
 else
  keyb.style.display="none";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer that works good..but when i uesd this ,the keys are not working..i try to get keyboard as shown in the link http://wk.w3tamil.com/index.php

Comment: can you tell me how to drag and drop the  keyboard anywhere on the screen.i used http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex11/domdrag/index.htm this link..but not working for me.